# Swift 3: Google maps not setting markers in for loop

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps

I have been trying to add multiple markers to google map using for loop but it does not add to the google map. Adding one marker works or if writing code for each marker without for loop.

Declaration

```
@IBOutlet weak var googleMapView: GMSMapView! // set in story board
var shopsLatLong = [Double: Double]()  // shops dictionary for lat long
```

For loop not working:

```
for (key,value) in shopsLatLong{
    //Setting camera
    self.googleMapView.camera = GMSCameraPosition.camera(withLatitude: key, longitude: value, zoom: 6.0)
    let marker = GMSMarker()
    marker.position = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(key, value)
    marker.title = "Store Name"
    marker.snippet = "Pakistan"
    marker.map = self.googleMapView
    print("Marker is \(marker)")
}
```

How to get this working? Kindly help me in figuring out this issue

Comment: do not init  gmsmarker out of loop

Comment: like using local variable for gmsmarker ?

Comment: yes local and change lat long

Comment: will you please replace you code from my code. it will work

Comment: @SaraMethuz see the code now, its like yours but not working

Comment: how many markers shows on googleMapView?

Comment: it can range from 1-4

Comment: But currently no marker is shown on map inside loop

Comment: you forgot marker icon marker.icon = image

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I also had a similar issue and I was able to figure it out. Actually I wasn't overriding prepare for segue and the button was also directly linked to the storyboard due to which my view presented it self first before I even got the data. So here is what I did maybe it works for you too.

> 1. Override prepare for segue and set the variables there
> 2. Remove the segue link (if any) which is linking directly with the button
> 3. Add new segue from the top of the view controller to the new segue.
> 4. Build and Run.

I hope it resolves the issue for you too.

Comment: Yes it worked!. I was sending data from one view to another view holding my map. I was trying to use do manual linking, while segue link from button was also present. So that's why my dictionary was not able to  load pointers to the map view

Answer (score 1):

Don't make `class variable` for marker. You have to create a `local variable` for the `marker`.

If you create a class variable then you will get only one marker. Because you are overriding the values inside the for loop

```
for (key,value) in shopsLatLong{
     //Get the latitude and longitude of the marker and pass it here.
      let lat = //latitude for marker
      let lon = //longitude for marker
      var marker = GMSMarker()
      marker.position = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(lat, lon)
      marker.title = "Store Name"
      marker.snippet = "Pakistan"
      marker.map = self.googleMapView
 }
```

Comment: Tried with local variable as well but no luck, as soon as I do for one marker outside the loop it works but fails in for loop

Comment: @UmarHussain are you getting different latitude and longitude inside the for loop?

Comment: yes @Subramanian I'm getting different latitude and longitude in for loop, which I'm getting from my database. It fails in the for loop to show these coordinates.

Answer (score 1):

First Create a array like

```
func setData(){
        //create dictionary and store in mai array
        var dicMapData : NSMutableDictionary = NSMutableDictionary()
        dicMapData["title"] = "Kalasagar Shopping Hub"
        dicMapData["image"] = "background9"
        dicMapData["subtitle"] = "ShoppingHub"
        dicMapData["latitude"] = 23.0669 // store latitude for specigic location
        dicMapData["longitude"] = 72.5328 // store longitude for specigic location
        arrMultipleAnotation.add(dicMapData)

        dicMapData = NSMutableDictionary()
        dicMapData["title"] = "Satadhar Cross Road"
        dicMapData["image"] = "background8"
        dicMapData["subtitle"] = "Crossroad"
        dicMapData["latitude"] = 23.0629
        dicMapData["longitude"] = 72.5328
        arrMultipleAnotation.add(dicMapData)

        dicMapData = NSMutableDictionary()
        dicMapData["title"] = "Sola Bridge"
        dicMapData["image"] = "menu-icon"
        dicMapData["subtitle"] = "Bridge"
        dicMapData["latitude"] = 23.0695
        dicMapData["longitude"] = 72.5232
        arrMultipleAnotation.add(dicMapData)

        let initialLocation = CLLocation(latitude: 23.0669, longitude: 72.5289)
        centerMapOnLocation(location: initialLocation)

        //For Displayig Multiple Pin in mapview using array and loop
        for locations in arrMultipleAnotation{
            //Setting camera
                self.googleMapView.camera = GMSCameraPosition.camera(withLatitude: dicCurrent["latitude"] as! Double, longitude: dicCurrent["longitude"] as! Double, zoom: 6.0)
                self.marker = GMSMarker()
                self.marker.position = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: dicCurrent["latitude"] as! Double, longitude: dicCurrent["longitude"] as! Double)
                self.marker.title = dicCurrent["title"] as? String
                self.marker.snippet = dicCurrent["subtitle"] as? String
                self.marker.map = self.googleMapView
                print("Marker is \(self.marker)")

        }
```

I hope It's work for you

Answer (score 0):

Change This code..

```
@IBOutlet weak var googleMapView: GMSMapView! // set in story board
var shopsLatLong = [Double: Double]()  // shops dictionary for lat long 


for (key,value) in shopsLatLong{
//Setting camera
      self.googleMapView.camera = GMSCameraPosition.camera(withLatitude: key, longitude: value, zoom: 6.0)
        let marker = GMSMarker()
        marker.position = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(key, value)
        marker.title = "Store Name"
        marker.icon = image
        marker.snippet = "Pakistan"
        marker.map = self.googleMapView
        print("Marker is \(self.marker)")
}
```

Comment: hi please check my answer 
@Sara Methuz

Comment: @Jaydip but your answer is given fixed marker not multiple

Comment: yes @Jaydip answer is hard coding but again for loop is the issue

Comment: @UmarHussain When you create a loop you can change the marker position as you want with using the latitude and longitude. When you using the single latitude and longitude it's over right the marker position.

Comment: @SaraMethuz my answer not fix if array value Three then loop execute Three time, show marker display  in three place. and its working

Comment: no coordinates for each marker are different :( , please see the updated question code.

Comment: @UmarHussain check my answer

Answer (score 0):

You should use a `markers` property, which is an array, and add your markers to this array.  That way there will be a strong reference to all of your marker objects and you can easily work with them.

Also, a dictionary isn't really a good data structure for this purpose.  I would suggest an array of struct where the struct has a latitude and longitude or even an array of tuples of `(Double,Double)`

```
@IBOutlet weak var googleMapView: GMSMapView! // set in story board
var shopsLatLong = [(Double,Double)]()  // shops dictionary for lat long
var markers = [GMSMarker]()


for (position) in shopsLatLong{
//Setting camera
      self.googleMapView.camera = GMSCameraPosition.camera(withLatitude: position.0, longitude: position.1, zoom: 6.0)
        let marker = GMSMarker()
        marker.position = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(position.0, position.1)
        marker.title = "Store Name"
        marker.snippet = "Pakistan"
        marker.map = self.googleMapView
        self.markers.append(marker)
        print("Marker is \(marker)")
}
```

Comment: your point is good, I tried it with checking array size of markers as well, markers array is correct but still the markers are not shown

Comment: This code works for me. A Dictionary isn't really the right structure to use, however. I changed it to an array of tuples with two doubles;  `[(Double,Double)]`.  Are you sure you are zoomed in enough to see the markers?

Comment: Yes I did zoomed in but still no markers. 
Also I'm using google maps in modal view, can this be the issue ?